# Gremlin - Best way to select properties from multiple vertices in single query

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have two related vertices with labels 'DeviceFamily' and 'Device'. They are related as shown below:

```
(DeviceFamily)-[:RELATION]->(Device)
```

The DeviceFamily vertex has a few properties say p,q,r and Device vertex has properties say x,y,z.

Given a Device id, if I require to find out x,y,z properties of the corresponding Device vertex and p,q,r properties of the related DeviceFamily, what query should I execute?

One solution I found is:

```
g.V('<id>').hasLabel('Device').as('d1', 'd2', 'd3').inE('RELATION').outV().as('f1', 'f2', 'f3').select('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3').by('x', 'y', 'z', 'p', 'q', 'r');
```

This query works but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should use some form of `project()`:

```
g.V('<id>').
  project('device','family').
    by(__.valueMap('x','y','z'))
    by(__.in('RELATION').valueMap('p','q','r'))
```

Note that I omitted the `hasLabel('Device')` as it's redundant as you know the unique identifier for the vertex. Further note that while I used `valueMap()` in the `by()` modulators of `project()` you could easily supply any Gremlin you want there to shape your data into those two keys (I just chose `valueMap()` as it's convenient to write).

If you'd like something more matched to your output you could still use `project()` in this direct fashion (i've been assuming there is only one "RELATION" edge - hope that is the case):

```
g.V('<id>').
  project('x','y','z','p','q','r').
    by('x').
    by('y').
    by('z').
    by(in('RELATION').values('p')).
    by(in('RELATION').values('q')).
    by(in('RELATION').values('r'))
```

I don't think most graph databases will optimize the final three `by()` modulators to a single traverse over the "RELATION" edge. I'd therefore suggest a slight adjustment - `project()` the edge instead:

```
g.V('<id>').
  inE('RELATION').
  project('x','y','z','p','q','r').
    by(inV().values('x')).
    by(inV().values('y')).
    by(inV().values('z')).
    by(outV().values('p')).
    by(outV().values('q')).
    by(outV().values('r'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This does give me the data as a map with keys 'device' and 'family' with their values in turn being another map that has the name of the properties as keys. Is there a way I can get a single map with keys x, y, z, p, q, r?

Comment: i added some other options if you need the map flattened. there's other methods to shape your result set. like, it's possible to merge two maps together, but didn't want to get into too much advanced Gremlin when these simple approaches could satisfy.